# rxjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Observable.throw is not a function at

Tags: angular, observable, angular6

I need to do rest operation adn catch erro and I do this:

```
import { Injectable,  } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response,Headers} from '@angular/http';

import { map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class RESTSERCIVE{

 getObject(id: number){
    return this.http.get(this.url+"/"+id).pipe(map(
      (response: Response)=>{return response.json()},
      ),
      catchError(this.handleErrorObservable)
      );
  }
 handleErrorObservable (error: Response | any) 
  {   
      return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

I don't why it give me this error. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because you are using Angular 6 and RxJS 6, the syntax for throwing erros has changed.

Do it this way instead,

```js
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

throwError(error.message || error);
```

Also in RxjS 6, you don't need to convert the response into JSON explicitly. It is done automatically. So you can remove the map from your code.

Hope this helps.