# I want to save data to a json database with angular

Tags: angular, http

I am creating a simple user loging app. All I want to do is have a form where the user inputs there email and password and this is saved to a json database.
I cant get the data to be save to the database I get a 500 internal error.

This is the code I am using

this is part of my auth.component (the form and the submit)

```
   createForm() {
    this.angForm = this.fb.group({
       email: ['', Validators.required ],
       password: ['', Validators.required ]
    });

    this.angForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));

    this.onValueChanged(); // (re)set form validation messages
  }

    onValueChanged(angFormData?: any) {

      this.user = this.angForm.value;
  }

  onSubmit() {
      this.authService
  .updateUsers(this.user)
  .subscribe(user => this.users.push(user));

  }

}
```

my service for saving the data

```
  updateUsers(user: User): Observable<User> {
   return this.http.post<User>(this.usersUrl, user, httpOptions).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}

private handleError(error: Response): Observable<any> {
  console.error("observable error: ", error);
  return throwError(error.statusText);
}
```

Here is a link to my sctakblitz with the complete app
https://angular-h4cnez.stackblitz.io

I am really new to angular

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error with `status code 500` It means there is an error in the backend.
If you would like to see your error in client-side change your service like the following:

```
updateUsers(user: User): Observable<User> {
   return this.http.post<User>(this.usersUrl, user, httpOptions).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}

private handleError(error: Response): Observable<any> {
  console.error("observable error: ", error);
  return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
}
```

Comment: I did this and it look like this is my error: ERROR TypeError: rxjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Observable.throw is not a function

Comment: see this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440245/rxjs-webpack-imported-module-3-observable-throw-is-not-a-function-at

Comment: I chnaged it like this updateUsers(user: User): Observable<User> {
   return this.http.post<User>(this.usersUrl, user, httpOptions).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}

private handleError(error: Response): Observable<any> {
  console.error("observable error: ", error);
  return throwError(error.statusText);
}
now I got the post 500 internal error

Comment: Check your backend code out because your error is in the backend

Comment: I am using a json server so as I understand there shouldnt be a problem there. Or for a json server am I supposed to do something to let it post to the database.

Comment: I get this in my json server console
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Function.createId (C:\Users\Natasha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\lib\server\mixins.js:57:39)
    at Function.insert (C:\Users\Natasha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\lodash-id\src\index.js:47:49)
    at C:\Users\Natasha\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\json-server\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4368:28
POST /users 500 15.868 ms - -

Comment: The problem was in my json database my array didnt have an ID